# Python: How to typing information in a simple attribute storage class?

Tags: python, collections, type-hinting, typing

I really appreciate [typing hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.htm) in Python. But I also love the flexibility of dynamic typing. I often use a pattern like:

```py
class Container(object):
    "simple but flexible attribute store"
    pass

def func1(arg) -> Container:
    # do some calculation with arg

    res = Container()
    res.x = 1
    res.y = "two"
    res.z = [3, 4, 5]

    return res

def func2(arg2):
    data = func1(arg2)

    # interesting line
    q = data.z[0]

    # ...
```

This is quite flexible because it allows to add new attributes to the container very easily. However I would also like to enable type-checking, such that the IDE after `# interesting line`

1. does **not** complain, that `Container`-object has no attribute `.z` and
2. also knows that `.z` is of type `list` or even (`List[int]`).

I would prefer a solution like e.g. `res = Container(a=int, b=str, c=List[int])`. Obviously the `Container`-class would need to get more complex for this but that would be fine. The instantiation of that class should stay as simple as possible, though.

I know about [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) but they do not seem to fit my need.

Comment: This does not seem to be possible. There are static code checkers for Python, [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), for example. However, these checkers cannot detect code changes at runtime, hence the name "static code checkers". You have to define your typed container properties. See this question for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903048/python-dynamic-properties-and-mypy

Comment: Seems like I desire a more compact (one-line) syntax to create a dataclass... probably I should simply accept the standard syntax.